# Problem changing the UI of a specific cell inside a gridview that is inside a view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, android-gridview

I have this problem with the UI, I made a calendar, which basically consists of a Gridview inside a ViewPager, and I want to show to highlight/make standout, the cell that show the current day. I managed to do that, the problem comes when the user swipes the ViewPager, the highlighted cell remains highlighted even though the date isn't correct (look at the pictures to understand).

I have 4 fragments that are reused to make the calendar, so when I swipe 4 times and then swipe back the problem disapears, so I think the problem is in the way I'm refreshing the ui on the adapter, but I don't know how to solve this.

[On startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LSmV.png)

[On swipe left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTxFW.png)(has you can see the day 12 is highligted)

Here's the code of my adapter:

```
    public void UpdateToday() { today = DateTime.Today; }

    public override DateTime this[int position] 
    {
        get { return datetimeList[position]; }
    }

    public override int Count 
    {
        get { return datetimeList.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View module = convertView;

        if (module == null)
        {
            module = LayoutInflater.From(context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.calendar_gridcell, null, false);
        }
        var textView = module.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.calendar_cell);


        if (datetimeList[position].Month == month)
            textView.SetTextColor(new Android.Graphics.Color(context.GetColor(Resource.Color.colorSecondary)));
        else            
            textView.SetTextColor(new Android.Graphics.Color(context.GetColor(Resource.Color.colorTextDarkSemiTransparent)));
        
        if (datetimeList[position].Month == today.Month && datetimeList[position].Day == today.Day)
        {
            textView.Background = context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.cell_today);
            textView.SetTextColor(new Android.Graphics.Color(context.GetColor(Resource.Color.colorAccent)));
        }             

        textView.Text = datetimeList[position].Day.ToString();
        module.SetPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

        return module;
    }
```

**Edit**

So the sulution was really simple, I just needed an else statement in the If that compared the item date to today's date:

```
        if (dateTimeList[position].Date == DateTime.Today)
        {
            textView.Background = context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.cell_today);
            textView.SetTextColor(new Android.Graphics.Color(context.GetColor(Resource.Color.colorAccent)));
        }
        else
        {
            if (dateTimeList[position].Month == month)
                textView.SetTextColor(new Android.Graphics.Color(context.GetColor(Resource.Color.colorSecondary)));
            else
                textView.SetTextColor(new Android.Graphics.Color(context.GetColor(Resource.Color.colorTextDarkSemiTransparent)));

            textView.Background = context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.cell_background);
        }
```

Comment: To be honest your question is not quite clear what exactly is the issue

Comment: the problem I have is, when I swipe the view pager, the previously marked cell is still marked, and I don't want that to happen. its only supposed to highlight the day of today. 
in the example, the first image shows the current day marked (it was the 15/10), but when I swipe left the day 12 is highlighted.

Comment: Then why not just mark datetime.today?

Comment: but I'm doing that

Comment: I have posted an answer explaining the reason take a look and revert in case you do not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I found was very simple what is happening here is that on the basis of DateTime.Today you first mark today's date.

But when you know you slide from one page to the other you are not un-marking that date so what happens is in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LSmV.png) case the current date is marked but when you move to the [next screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTxFW.png) you are not un-marking the background so it still stays the same.

Revert in case this does not make sense.

Comment: I think I understood, it was in fact really simple, I can't belive I missed it out, thank you!

Comment: Sure no problem in case there is an issue let me know!